# phonegap windows 10 published app exits upon startup

Tags: cordova, phonegap, windows-10-mobile

I have a phonegap app that is working in Android, iOS and Windows 8.1 (using "phonegap build wp8") but the build for Windows 10 (using "phonegap build windows") is giving a problem.

If I run it from Visual Studio, it runs OK on the emulator and on a Windows 10 device plugged into the PC but if I create an app bundle (or upload to store) the resultant file does not run, it just a exits after the splash screen is displayed.

I'm using phonegap 7.1.1,
npm 3.10.10,
Visual Studio 2017 (15.4.5)

config.xml as follows (emails and domain names obfuscated)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget android-versionCode="26020005" id="com.example.goinspect" ios-CFBundleVersion="2.6.2.5" version="2.6.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>xx-xxx</name>
<description>
    xxx
</description>
<author email="xxx@example.com" href="http://www.example.com">
    xxx
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#4b4a4a" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="FullScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
<preference name="windows-arch" value="ARM" />
<platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
</platform>
<platform name="wp8">
    <icon height="99" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icon/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" />
    <icon height="159" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icon/wp8/Background.png" width="159" />
    <splash height="1280" platform="wp8" src="www/res/screen/wp8/screen-portrait.jpg" width="768" />
</platform>
<platform name="windows">
    <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" />
    <icon height="30" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" />
    <icon height="50" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="120" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="44" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" />
    <icon height="106" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" />
    <icon height="70" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" />
    <icon height="71" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" />
    <icon height="170" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" />
    <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" />
    <icon height="310" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
    <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
    <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" />
    <splash height="1920" platform="windows" src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" />
    <preference name="WindowsStoreIdentityName" value="KoresupportLimited.go-inspect" />
    <Identity Name="KoresupportLimited.go-inspect" Publisher="CN=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenSpinnerColor" value="white" />
    <preference name="WindowsToastCapable" value="true" />
</platform>
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*://*.example.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="*://*.example.com:8757/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
<engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
<engine name="windows" spec="~4.4.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^2.4.1">
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Take Photos of Issues Arising on inspection" />
    <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Use Photos of Issues taken before inspection was started" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.7" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="^1.3.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^2.4.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" spec="^1.1.5">
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="26.+" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
<plugin name="pushwoosh-cordova-plugin" spec="^6.5.3">
    <variable name="IOS_FOREGROUND_ALERT_TYPE" value="ALERT" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_FOREGROUND_PUSH" value="false" />
    <variable name="LOG_LEVEL" value="DEBUG" />
</plugin>
</widget>
```

26Jan18 New Info: I found the crash log that suggests it's the pushwoosh plugin.

```
reference_error_text_ms-appx-web://koresupportlimited.go-inspect/www/plugins/pushwoosh-cordova-plugin/src/windows/pushwooshpluginproxy.js:28:29___________anonymous_function()_800a1391_koresupportlimited.go-inspect_com.koresupport.goinspect!unknown_function
```

We originally did this app in Android and iOS, at that time the name having a dash in it (go-inspect) was no problem to either platform but Visual Studio doesn't like it so we took it out (goinspect) so I'm wondering if that is what pushwoosh is getting confused about. Only thing is where to go from here.

Comment: Have you tried to create the app in release model?

Comment: Yes, I thought for while it was to do with re-associating it with a another app name (we have the same app name but with "-beta" on the end) which meant it could not find its index.html. But in doing a build with the original app name and side loading onto a phone it now exits after showing the splash screen.

Comment: Try to run you app in release mode in device connected to PC. Another thing you can do is to enable app feedback option enabled from settings. It will generate a dump file. You can further use that file to check crashing details.